# php insert multiple rows in my sql database for every checked checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

Say i have the following form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
</BR>
<?php
// create two dropdowns with ajax
echo "<font id=\"categoria\"><select>\n";
echo "<option value='0'>Select the Firm</option> \n" ;
echo "</select></font>\n";
?>
<?php
echo "<font id=\"subcategoria\"><select>\n";
echo "<option value='0'>Select the Claims Hub</option> \n" ;
echo "</select></font>\n";
?>

<form method="post" align= "right">
<table >

    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
    <tr>
         <td style="text-align: left; ">Criminal  </td>
         <td align="left" >
            <input type="checkbox" name="mattertype" value="1" />
         </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
    <tr>
         <td style="text-align: left; ">Labour  </td>
         <td align="left" >
            <input type="checkbox" name="mattertype" value="1" />
         </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
    <tr>
         <td style="text-align: left; ">Civil  </td>
         <td align="left" >
            <input type="checkbox" name="mattertype" value="1" />
         </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
     <tr>
         <td style="text-align: left; ">Active  </td>
         <td align="left" >
            <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="1" />
         </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" align= "right" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

How would i write the php code to insert the following information as a new record for all the checked checkboxes?  For example, i have checked Civil, Labour and Active.  I now want the first record that must be inserted to read

Firm                Area                      Mattertype          Active (my sql table)

value of categoria    value of subcategoria   Civl                1
value of categoria    value of subcategoria   Labour              1

If any or all of the civil, labour or criminal checkboxes are ticked it must insert the value of categoria, value of subcatgoria, first ticked checkbox (mattertype) and if active is ticked then a 1 for active .

Then for the second record again value of categoria, value of subcatgoria, second ticked checkbox (mattertype) and if active is ticked then a 1 for active .

And so on.  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change the mattertype checkbox to use an array for the values, and change the values to something unique for each one (1 for criminal, 2 for labour, 3 for civil)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mattertype[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="mattertype[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="mattertype[]" value="3" />
```

PHP

```
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
$subcategoria = $_POST['subcategoria'];
$mattertypes = $_POST['mattertype'];
$active = $_POST['active'] == 1 ? 1 : 0;

//$matertypes will be an array so loop over it
foreach( $mattertypes as $type ) {
  switch( $type ) {
     case '1':
       $typename = "Criminal";
     break;
     case '2':
       $typename = "Labour";
     break;
     case '3':
       $typename = "Civil";
     break;
  }
  $SQL = "INSERT into mytable (categoria,subcategoria,mattertype,active) VALUES('$categoria','$subcategoria','$typename','$active')";

  //Do the call to database with the query.
}
```

Of course sanitize your data before putting it into the database.

Comment: Works like a bomb.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**in html**

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="mattertype[]" value="1" />
```

**in php**

```
//get mattertype which are checked by

$_POST['mattertype'];// this is come as array then use according to your requirement
```

Comment: this will make the mattertype an array, but they would also have to change the values as otherwise this will just produce an array of 1's and and you wouldnt be able to tell which of criminal, labour, or civil were chosen.

Comment: yes i agree with you but my main concern on name property hope it make sense and thanks for your advice......

Answer (score 0):

Make checkbox name as  `name="mattertype[]"` and change values as well.

Then post as `$_POST['mattertype'];`